# struggling in integer string conversion

Tags: java

ok this my first question here i hope i well learn something .so basically i have this project of encryption and decryption the hard part is to convert string to int so i can preform some logic operation on them then represent them back to string(encrypted text) then convert string(encrypted text) back to integers and reverse the opration and convert the result to decrypted message`

```
System.out.println("enter the statment you wish to encode");
String plaintext=sc.nextLine();
int [] a=new int[plaintext.length()+1];

for ( int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); ++i ) {
    char c = plaintext.charAt( i );
    int ascii = (int) c;
    System.out.print(ascii); 
    a[i]=ascii;
}

System.out.println("||||");
for(int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(a[i]^6 ); 
}

System.out.println("||||");
String str = Arrays.toString(a);
System.out.println("str.."+str);

/*for ( int c = 0; c <plaintext.length(); ++c) {

char pointer=a.charAt();
}
```

I know it is a mess so basically i convert string into `int[]` 
but how i can convert back the `int[]` to string?? chatAt()wont work so what is the solution string array meby??

Comment: If you can, convert string to bytes (byte array) and encrypt each byte. Conversion of string to byte array and back is very well supported in Java.

Comment: well i tried that and i failed i think this is much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println("enter the statment you wish to encode");

String plaintext=sc.nextLine();
int [] a=new int[plaintext.length()];
for ( int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++) {
   char c = plaintext.charAt(i);
   int ascii = (int) c;
   System.out.print(ascii); 
   a[i]=ascii;
}
System.out.println("||||");

for(int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(a[i]^6 ); 
}
System.out.println("||||");

String str = Arrays.toString(a);
System.out.println("str.."+str);

String str2 = "";
for ( int c = 0; c < a.length(); c++) {
    str2 += (char)a[c];
}

System.out.println("str2.."+str2);
```